# Bucle con una función SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, while

Buen día necesito hacer una función que llame a función Factorial y haga la siguiente sumatoria.

e=1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+(1/3!)+(1/n!)

```
CREATE FUNCTION Factorial (@a int)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i INT

IF @a <= 1
    SET @i =1 
else
    set @i = @a * dbo.Factorial(@a-1)
return @i
end

select dbo.Factorial(11) 'Numero facotrial'


CREATE FUNCTION examen(@a int)
RETURNS FLOAT 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @b float, 
            @c float;
    SET @c = (SELECT dbo.Factorial(@a))
    WHILE(@b <= @c)
    BEGIN
        SET @b = 1 / @c
    END 

    SET @b = @b + 1
    RETURN @b
END
GO

SELECT dbo.examen(10)
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Necesito llamar a la funcion que cree llamada factorial y hacer un blucle while para hacer una sumatoria e= 1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+(1/3!)+(1/n!)

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, tienes varios problemas en la definición. Esa función no calcula el factorial, sino una suma de los inversos de factoriales. También es incorrecto que trates de regresar un entero cuando siempre regresarás algo menor a 3 y la mayor parte del tiempo será mayor a 2.

Dicho eso, no necesitas utilizar la recursividad. Eso también prevendrá errores al llegar al límite de procesos anidados de SQL Server. Sólo necesitas un WHILE con algunas variables.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SumaInversoFactorial (
    @a int
)
RETURNS FLOAT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int = 1,
            @r float = 1,
            @f float = 1;

    WHILE @i <= @a
        SELECT @r = @r + 1/(@i*@f),
               @f = @i * @f,
               @i = @i + 1;


    RETURN @r;
END;
GO

SELECT dbo.SumaInversoFactorial( 11);

GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.SumaInversoFactorial;
```

Si se quiere hacer con 2 funciones, lo ideal es hacer una para el factorial de cualquier número y otra para recorrer la serie. Esta es una mala idea porque estaremos haciendo 2 ciclos en vez de uno, lo cual implica más trabajo y menos eficiencia.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Factorial (@a int)
RETURNS int 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @f int = 1;

WHILE @a >= 1
    SELECT @f = @f * @a,
           @a -= 1;

RETURN @f;
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION SumaInversoFactorial2 (@a int)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@a) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
select 1 + SUM( CAST( 1 AS float) / dbo.Factorial(n)) 'Numero Factorial'
FROM cteTally;

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.SumaInversoFactorial2(5) sif;

GO
DROP FUNCTION Factorial, SumaInversoFactorial2;
```

Comment: Entiendo que el valor debe de ser menos a 3, pero la funcion Factorial que hice solo hace el calculo del factorial un numero n, necesito dos funciones, primero la que calcula el factorial y despues una que calcule sumas de euler utilizando a la funcion factorial

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas dos funciones si puedes usar solo una?

Comment: Se que se puede hacer solo en una, pero me estan pidiendo que se utilicen 2 :(

Comment: Intente hacerlo pero me manda como resultado NULL