# Error al calcular formula en base a una función SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, condiciones

Quiero añadir una función que calcule el número de Euler en base a un factorial en SQL, pero no se si este haciendo mi programación bien en base a la función que tengo declarada. 
El número que me debe arrojar es el **2,71828**

Dejaré mi código esperando su ayuda. GRACIAS

/Factorial/

```
alter function factorial(@num float(5))
returns float
begin
declare @fact float
if @num = 0 or @num = 1
select @fact = 1
else
select @fact = dbo.factorial(@num -1) * @num
return @fact
endselect [dbo].factorial (20)
```

/*euler*/

```
alter function euler (@e float(10))
returns float
begin
declare @i float=1, @sum float=0
while(@i <= @e)
begin
set @sum  =1+(1/(select [dbo].factorial (@i)))
set @i=@i+1
end
return @sum
end
select [dbo].euler (3)
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Bucle con una función SQL SERVER](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305823/bucle-con-una-funci%c3%b3n-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes corregir la funcion euler de la siguiente forma:

```
alter function euler (@e float(10))
returns float
begin
declare @i float=1, 
        @sum float=1

while(@i <= @e)
begin
    set @sum  = @sum+(1/(select [dbo].factorial (@i)))
    set @i=@i+1
end
return @sum
end
```

Mientras más grande el parámetro que envías a la función más se acerca al número e.
Espero te sirva.